# ios crash log symbolicate dsym

Tags: ios, app-store, crash-log

I was refused six times for ipv6 reasons.

The problem was that the app would exit when run. 
I developed it using firebase sdk.

I received the log, but the symbolic is not working properly, so I do not know where it is wrong.

I entered the following command in the terminal.

> xcrun atos -o 비나이다.app/비나이다 -arch arm64 -l 0x00000001001048bc

There is no response.

Attach DSYM and crash log. Please help me if possible

[download dsym & log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12168496/ipv6.zip)

> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an
>   IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch
>   without crashing.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
>   Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash
>   Reports.
>
> For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please
>   refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and Supporting IPv6-only
>   Networks.
>
> For a networking overview, please see About Networking.

```
{"app_name":"비나이다","timestamp":"2017-01-11 15:52:27.98 -0800","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"f984b6b2-c7ec-3316-9526-de94e9866632","adam_id":0,"build_version":"8","bundleID":"com.jdc2.linkU","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)","incident_id":"C97E4BF7-5B61-430C-A83A-E1DE906BA742","name":"비나이다"}
Incident Identifier: C97E4BF7-5B61-430C-A83A-E1DE906BA742
CrashReporter Key:   64d0ed0f289267f688fb730e497e716089942b8b
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             비나이다 [2374]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FE2CB3E7-BAED-493C-B486-229142EE2E45/비나이다.app/비나이다
Identifier:          com.jdc2.linkU
Version:             8 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.jdc2.linkU [1030]


Date/Time:           2017-01-11 15:52:27.9498 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-01-11 15:52:27.1928 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x185c7d1b8 0x1846b455c 0x1001b7b54 0x1001acdb4 0x10006c478 0x10006c35c 0x18bb32924 0x18bb324ec 0x18bebd4e4 0x18be846d0 0x18be80b44 0x18bdc3fdc 0x18bdb5d50 0x18bdcf09c 0x185c2aa44 0x185c2a240 0x185c28094 0x185b562b8 0x18760a198 0x18bb9d7fc 0x18bb98534 0x1000708bc 0x184b395b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b014 0x184c2c000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d13450 0x184d0e000 + 21584
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184bbf49c 0x184b5c000 + 406684
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184bbf40c 0x184b5c000 + 406540
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001846892d4 0x184688000 + 4820
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001846a6cc0 0x184688000 + 126144
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001846b4844 0x1846ac000 + 34884
7   비나이다                        0x00000001000ced50 0x100064000 + 437584
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001846a366c 0x184688000 + 112236
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001846a3234 0x184688000 + 111156
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001846b471c 0x1846ac000 + 34588
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b5632c 0x185b4d000 + 37676
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018760a198 0x1875fe000 + 49560
13  UIKit                           0x000000018bb9d7fc 0x18bb23000 + 501756
14  UIKit                           0x000000018bb98534 0x18bb23000 + 480564
15  비나이다                        0x00000001000708bc 0x100064000 + 51388
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184b395b8 0x184b35000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4ba88 0x184c2c000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0f344 0x184d0e000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed8c 0x184d0e000 + 3468

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x174133240.events
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2d1dc 0x184c2c000 + 4572
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b18770 0x184b05000 + 79728
2   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dc73358 0x18dc70000 + 13144
3   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dc78474 0x18dc70000 + 33908
4   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dc78274 0x18dc70000 + 33396
5   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dcc3fc0 0x18dc70000 + 344000
6   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dcc0608 0x18dc70000 + 329224
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dcc0528 0x18dc70000 + 329000
8   CoreLocation                    0x000000018dcc1be0 0x18dc70000 + 334816
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000184d4f8f4 0x184d4a000 + 22772
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000184d4d3e8 0x184d4a000 + 13288
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b0628c 0x184b05000 + 4748
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b09d80 0x184b05000 + 19840
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b14210 0x184b05000 + 61968
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b091e0 0x184b05000 + 16864
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b14210 0x184b05000 + 61968
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b099a4 0x184b05000 + 18852
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b14210 0x184b05000 + 61968
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b099a4 0x184b05000 + 18852
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b1526c 0x184b05000 + 66156
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b1baf8 0x184b05000 + 92920
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0f14c 0x184d0e000 + 4428
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed8c 0x184d0e000 + 3468

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed88 0x184d0e000 + 3464

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2d188 0x184c2c000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2cff8 0x184c2c000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c2a5d0 0x185b4d000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c281ec 0x185b4d000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b562b8 0x185b4d000 + 37560
5   Foundation                      0x000000018669326c 0x186687000 + 49772
6   Foundation                      0x00000001866b3dd0 0x186687000 + 183760
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c511c38 0x18bb23000 + 10415160
8   Foundation                      0x0000000186790e68 0x186687000 + 1089128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.fira.worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2f444 0x184c2c000 + 13380
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001861d1700 0x186166000 + 440064
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001861d1384 0x186166000 + 439172
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001861bdee4 0x186166000 + 360164
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018618bbac 0x186166000 + 154540
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001861b7040 0x186166000 + 331840
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001861a7a7c 0x186166000 + 268924
7   비나이다                        0x0000000100107cbc 0x100064000 + 670908
8   비나이다                        0x0000000100107c2c 0x100064000 + 670764
9   비나이다                        0x0000000100105af8 0x100064000 + 662264
10  비나이다                        0x0000000100105788 0x100064000 + 661384
11  비나이다                        0x00000001001189d8 0x100064000 + 739800
12  비나이다                        0x000000010010fcd8 0x100064000 + 703704
13  비나이다                        0x000000010011db4c 0x100064000 + 760652
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b061bc 0x184b05000 + 4540
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b06fb0 0x184b05000 + 8112
16  비나이다                        0x000000010011d840 0x100064000 + 759872
17  비나이다                        0x000000010011d61c 0x100064000 + 759324
18  비나이다                        0x000000010012fea4 0x100064000 + 835236
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b061fc 0x184b05000 + 4604
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b061bc 0x184b05000 + 4540
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b143dc 0x184b05000 + 62428
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b099a4 0x184b05000 + 18852
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b1634c 0x184b05000 + 70476
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184b160ac 0x184b05000 + 69804
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0f2a0 0x184d0e000 + 4768
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed8c 0x184d0e000 + 3468

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4ba88 0x184c2c000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0f344 0x184d0e000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed8c 0x184d0e000 + 3468

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed88 0x184d0e000 + 3464

Thread 8 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2d188 0x184c2c000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2cff8 0x184c2c000 + 4088
2   비나이다                        0x00000001000bcca4 0x100064000 + 363684
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2d188 0x184c2c000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2cff8 0x184c2c000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c2a5d0 0x185b4d000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c281ec 0x185b4d000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b562b8 0x185b4d000 + 37560
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018635b8f0 0x18627c000 + 915696
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186790e68 0x186687000 + 1089128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed88 0x184d0e000 + 3464

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2d188 0x184c2c000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c2cff8 0x184c2c000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c2a5d0 0x185b4d000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c281ec 0x185b4d000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b562b8 0x185b4d000 + 37560
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f7ebd24 0x19f776000 + 482596
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f811d9c 0x19f776000 + 638364
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b314 0x184c2c000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184b6925c 0x184b5c000 + 53852
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000184679994 0x184632000 + 293268
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a45a3ec 0x189b81000 + 9278444
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a459438 0x189b81000 + 9274424
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a459274 0x189b81000 + 9273972
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a459114 0x189b81000 + 9273620
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a45a4d8 0x189b81000 + 9278680
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a45a404 0x189b81000 + 9278468
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a45a6b4 0x189b81000 + 9279156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 13 name:  WebThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4ae64 0x184c2c000 + 126564
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d14da4 0x184d0e000 + 28068
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d14fa8 0x184d0e000 + 28584
3   WebCore                         0x000000018a75db28 0x18a6f6000 + 424744
4   WebCore                         0x000000018a75da88 0x18a6f6000 + 424584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c2a0c0 0x185b4d000 + 905408
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c27cf0 0x185b4d000 + 896240
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c28330 0x185b4d000 + 897840
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b562b8 0x185b4d000 + 37560
9   WebCore                         0x000000018a75b660 0x18a6f6000 + 415328
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11850 0x184d0e000 + 14416
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d11760 0x184d0e000 + 14176
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed94 0x184d0e000 + 3476

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d0ed88 0x184d0e000 + 3464

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000184d0d314  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000184bd6772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000050000000500  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001ab549c40  x21: 0x000000016fd9b4a0  x22: 0x0000000000000007  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000174016550  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd9bba8   fp: 0x000000016fd9b3c0   lr: 0x0000000184d13450
    sp: 0x000000016fd9b3a0   pc: 0x0000000184c4b014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100064000 - 0x10040bfff 비나이다 arm64  <f984b6b2c7ec33169526de94e9866632> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/FE2CB3E7-BAED-493C-B486-229142EE2E45/비나이다.app/비나이다
0x1005e0000 - 0x10060ffff dyld arm64  <f54ed85a94253887886a8028e20ed8ba> /usr/lib/dyld
0x184630000 - 0x184631fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <6c1de96c8fe5363cab2ef76f891c6e22> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x184632000 - 0x184687fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <b2db8b1d09283b7bafe1b2933adc5dfd> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x184688000 - 0x1846a8fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <e3419bbaface31b5970c6c8d430be26d> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1846ac000 - 0x184a85fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <538f809dcd7c35ceb59d99802248f045> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x184a86000 - 0x184a8afff libcache.dylib arm64  <f09cab6893c631218f817e61b3d77fcb> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x184a8b000 - 0x184a96fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e071643355cd3f67bae19045c7f9f340> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x184a97000 - 0x184a9afff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <8209cb28df5d3b48894899019fcbb344> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x184a9b000 - 0x184aa2fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <567f33ef4d8f3e48a5afac933ccd389f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x184aa3000 - 0x184b04fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <056a6c201d3d3696b59f0b264ba9b972> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x184b05000 - 0x184b34fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <fb1d0baf642337d1bea0af309586df97> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x184b35000 - 0x184b39fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <6ebb575f616935cbbef02f2c031490d1> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x184b3a000 - 0x184b3afff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <ceb57f62c49e38d8a8d33309db668bd3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x184b3b000 - 0x184b40fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <20627f9f062c3ee8873e3ab3bc3fda8c> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x184b41000 - 0x184b42fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <43110ffd953537e28981c6dead2c0b1f> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x184b43000 - 0x184b5afff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <e52a49b27e963d2bb90332a5b0895f8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x184b5b000 - 0x184b5bfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <480fe954b3f63f16af8acfd6dc34e2da> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x184b5c000 - 0x184bdafff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <8a5a190d70563f3c8d4ce16cab74f599> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x184bdb000 - 0x184bdffff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <7628c33e4c383a78b0e33cf403e6f019> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x184be0000 - 0x184be5fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <9de64e7545ab359fb9cefc695aa510f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x184be6000 - 0x184be7fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <e61211f8f4c9399595fbd921e8589a8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x184be8000 - 0x184c00fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <14fa1ba4b14b338181c2ef87b214695e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x184c01000 - 0x184c07fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <7d745bdfb72e3119bad43c36f60a5a8a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x184c08000 - 0x184c2bfff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <6546bc8b4fa23df898bf2471e801d50b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x184c2c000 - 0x184c50fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <9ec307fcdd2f3f728f37ec6e0186df20> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x184c51000 - 0x184c7dfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <ba786894a7213d37baa99aafc0ee5493> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x184c7e000 - 0x184c99fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <c57ecb4ada5c3930a580b3d07583058a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x184c9a000 - 0x184cf1fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <efa018a4cb4936e3b77b9194d390efc4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x184cf2000 - 0x184cfbfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <34c2d9c2986f32dd996e4e439d94c9c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x184cfc000 - 0x184d06fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <605beaf21db73cc3ae98a65e8c11f7d0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x184d07000 - 0x184d0dfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <518e18adfdfc316e9b4d519f6e4b6a47> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x184d0e000 - 0x184d17fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <d8480fc3a35d3475b0d12553c761d8cb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x184d18000 - 0x184d1bfff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <89419e71367637d590768d37ca10d9a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x184d1c000 - 0x184d23fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <832499573c1730b48f6ff8e7c06fae15> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x184d24000 - 0x184d42fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <27778d14d3cb3239a6bb52a2461cd543> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x184d43000 - 0x184d48fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <7a7545249f7d3a69a162acb73ec4f17a> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x184d49000 - 0x184d49fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <21d158555a6233b19c53df16cafb6974> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x184d4a000 - 0x184d70fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <8f1330e254b83bd3a973af6933b91836> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x184d71000 - 0x184f8bfff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <35fc5fa2aab8326897081ab8416c497c> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x184f8c000 - 0x184f9cfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <b3ab59ff330f3225a53b4e8e95440d77> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x185b4d000 - 0x185ed1fff CoreFoundation arm64  <dd9791d198ef32eea1335b8ebc9b3d55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x185ed2000 - 0x185ee2fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <788093e9b6b738cea7045bfec4bef1d8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x185ee3000 - 0x185ee3fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <3bcefd094fa83b26807a1c6c92933cd2> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x185ee4000 - 0x185f5ffff IOKit arm64  <e0a6f4f0810b3f75813eda2afebd591c> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x185f60000 - 0x185f80fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <1e9e78da74143c54bb1e50aa7e285a0f> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x185f81000 - 0x18606bfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <b3fc55542fe33491877c661cf410b164> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x18606c000 - 0x1860fafff Security arm64  <88e5d6eb0de13ff6b7904f1b0e43a88e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1860fb000 - 0x186165fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <d907035d1ff936e5986035f50a77f5d3> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x186166000 - 0x18627bfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <87863a80836a3d659e5485f5029c3ed4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18627c000 - 0x186615fff CFNetwork arm64  <d63319a4fe2738dfb695ceb729f9b972> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x186616000 - 0x186626fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <0d14fa7337f43079bad2a4cfc6d66b70> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x186627000 - 0x18663ffff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <b90cea0595ff3f8599d9788e1d2cb454> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x186640000 - 0x18665afff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <ac663b865b6b38429a40878701aa484a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x18665b000 - 0x186684fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <667b9f199ef63c89b05bf1ea9a3ffe13> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x186685000 - 0x186686fff liblangid.dylib arm64
```

Comment: did u get a solution on this ?